# reflexive, symmetric and not transitive relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a relation on a set $R$ is reflexive, symmetric but not transitive, does it imply that all the classes $[x] = \{ y\mid xRy\}$ are mutually exclusive, in the sense that for no $[x]$ and $[y]$, they both share an element, and so their intersection is always empty?

Comment: A more visual way to think about this is that your construction of a reflexive and symmetric [but not transitive] closure is making R into an undirected graph with self-loops. A class [x] as you defined it is simply the set of vertices adjacent to x [in this undirected graph], x itself included. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacentVertices.html Clearly you can build a line graph 1 -- 2 -- 3 in which 2 is adjacent to everyone but 1 and 3 are not adjacent to each other. This is gerw's anwer, in graph terms.

Comment: In case it's not clear what I meant by self-loop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 3):

I am not pretty sure whether I understood your question correctly, but on the set $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ the relation
$$R = \{ (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3)\}$$
might be a counterexample. The classes
$$[1], [2], [3]$$
are pairwise different, but $2$ is in all classes.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a counter-example. If we replace not-transitiviy with transitivity, than we obtain an equivalence relation with classes that are pairwise disjoint. Is transitivity responsible for this?

Comment: This corresponds to the cover $\{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}\}$ of $\Omega$ in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a set $X$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is any cover of it, so $\bigcup \mathcal{U} = X$, then we have such a relation in $xRy$ iff $\exists O \in \mathcal{U}: \{x,y\} \subseteq O$. It’s trivially symmetric and reflexive. Gerw’s answer is a special case.

The “class” of $x$ is then just $\bigcup\{O \in \mathcal{U}\mid x \in O\}$, which is usually denoted $\textrm{St}(x,\mathcal{U})$, the star of $x$ wrt the cover. If the cover is disjoint, we exactly get the equivalence relation with those elements as classes, otherwise we get some non-transitivity and other classes too.

Answer (score 0):

Take any non-trivial equivalence relation $R$ on a set $X$ (where equivalence relation means a relation that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, and where, by non-trivial, I mean that there is at least one pair $x, y \in X$ with $\lnot x \mathrel{R} y$). (E.g., define $R$ by $x \mathrel R y \Leftrightarrow x \cong y \;(\mbox{mod $2$})$ on $X = \Bbb{Z}$.) Let's find a way to extend $R$ to a relation on a larger set $X'$ that is not transitive.

Let $X' = X \cup \{*\}$ where $*$ is some object that does not belong to $X$ and define $x \mathrel{R'} y$ to hold iff $x, y \in X$ and $x \mathrel{R} y$ or at least one of $x$ and $y$ is *. So we've added something to $X$ that is related to everything while keeping the original relation on pairs of elements of $X$. $R'$ cannot be transitive, because there are $x, y \in X$ with $\lnot x \mathrel{R'} y$, but $x \mathrel{R'} *$ and $* \mathrel{R'} y$. However, $x \in [*] \cap [x]$ for every $x$ in $x$. So the classes $[z]$ for $z \in X'$ are certainly not disjoint.

I see another answer has appeared while I have been typing this. The example in that answer is a specific instance of the above construction.

Comment: Thanks. So an equivalence relation is transitive and this implies that the classes are pairwise disjoint. If we drop the transitivity, this can hold, but it is not a necessary requirement,right?

Comment: The classes for an equivalence relation are pairwise disjoint in the sense that either $[x] \cap [y] = \emptyset$ or $[x] \cap [y] = [x]$ (but the latter case does not imply $x = y$, instead, it implies $x\mathrel{R}y$). I've updated my answer to try to explain that the motivation is how to extend an equivalence relation so that it is no longer transitive.